# Can Windows Server be a KMS client to AWS, but also a host for Office clients?

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-office, kms

I want to use a micro Windows Server instance on Amazon as a KMS host for Microsoft Office. The Windows Server instance is already set up as a KMS client getting its keys from Amazon for WS 2012.

Is it possible to still have it get its activation from Amazon, but also set the server up as a host for my Office clients?